# I Cant Get My Tkinter Checkbutton Variable Value Using .get()

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have been working on a project and recently encountered an issue with my check button. Whenever I try to do `variablenname.get()`, it never works as it says `int value has no attribute get()`. I did use `variablename = IntVar()` too, what I am trying to do is to make if statements dependant on the value of the checkbutton.

```
        var = IntVar()
        BTR = Tk()
        Discounts = Checkbutton(BTR, text="Discount (Students, Under 18s, 65+ and Disability Badge Holders)", font = ("times", 30), bg="#252538", fg = "#99FFFF", variable = var)
        Discounts.place(x=120, y=300)
        PriceTag=Label(BTR, text =("£", Cost), font = ("times", 50), fg = "White", bg = "#252538")
        PriceTag.place(x=1000, y= 450)
        val=Label(BTR, text = Tickets, font = ("times", 22), height = 5, width = 15, bg= "White")
        val.place(x=175, y=550)
        add=Button(BTR, text = "+", font = ("times", 22), height = 5, width = 10, bg = "#B266FF", command = lambda: UpdateAdd(val, BTR, PriceTag, BusTicketPrice, price, var))
        add.place(x=420, y=550)

    def UpdateAdd(val, BTR, PriceTag, BusTicketPrice, price, var):
      var = var.get()
      Tickets = Tickets + 1 
      val.destroy()
      val = Label(BTR, text = Tickets, font = ("times", 22), height = 5, width = 15, bg= "White")
      val.place(x=175, y=550)
      PriceTag.destroy()
      if price == "Peak" and var == 0 :
          BusTicketPrice=BusTicketPrice*1.25
      elif var == 1 and price == "Peak":
          BusTicketPrice=BusTicketPrice
      elif var == 1 and price == "Off-Peak":
          BusTicketPrice=BusTicketPrice*0.75
      elif price == "Off-Peak" and var == 0):
          BusTicketPrice=BusTicketPrice
      Cost = BusTicketPrice * Tickets
      Cost = round(Cost, 3)
      PriceTag=Label(BTR, text =("£", str(Cost), "0"), font = ("times", 50), fg = "White", bg = "#252538")
      PriceTag.place(x=1000, y= 450)
```

Comment: variable value using .get()

Comment: Could you edit your code to only show the relevant code to your question

Comment: I have assigned root window to my main screen of my program do to the inserting of pictures in labels to my program, I have edited the code removing the unnecessary parts however the problem still is that the variable has not attribute of get()

Comment: My answer explains why `var` in `UpdateAdd` no longer has a `.get` attribute. Thanks for editing your code, but it's still not runnable. Please read about making a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with this code. Firstly, you should not attempt to create any Tkinter objects, including widgets and IntVars, until after you've created the root window and started the Tcl interpreter with the `Tk()` call. I'm surprised that your code doesn't print an error message like

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

because you have `var = IntVar()` before `BTR = Tk()`. I didn't try to run the code you posted because it isn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The main cause of your bug is that in `UpdateAdd` you do `var = var.get()` near the start of the function (which gets the integer value from `var` and then binds that integer object to the name `var`), but then a bit further down you have `var.get()`, and that won't work because now `var` refers to the integer object, not the `IntVar` it was originally bound to.

Here's a minimal program that demonstrates that using an IntVar with a Checkbutton does work as intended.

```
import tkinter as tk

BTR = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()

title = tk.Label(BTR, text="Purchase Bus or Tram Tickets")
title.pack()

discounts = tk.Checkbutton(BTR, text="Discount", variable=var)
discounts.pack()

test = tk.Button(BTR, text="test", command=lambda: print(var.get()))
test.pack()

BTR.mainloop()
```

When you press the "test" button, the current state of the Checkbutton will be printed to the console.